# Running two spec folders in Rails with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm currently trying to rewrite an application's FactoryGirl factories and therefore I am looking to run two spec folders. Maybe a `spec` folder and an `old_spec` folder. However there always seems to be conflicts as FactoryGirl doesn't seem to know whether to use the original factories or the new versions... Obviously I would like to have both folders integrated with my CI server as Im re-writing & so therefore I require both folders to be ran. Does anybody have any experience running two spec folders and could offer any advice?

Comment: Why not use branches in git instead?

Comment: Use a branch; `git checkout -b spike/rewrite-factories`. That way your work won't interfere with the current master until it's ready.

Comment: It's going to be an ongoing thing, that will slowly be added to over time... I'd rather both things were working in conjunction with one and other straight away...

Comment: and we have ALOT of factories... ;)

Comment: The refactoring branch can co-exist with your main branch and changes could be merged into it.