# Running Multiple Factories of the Same Object in Production

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

At work, we're using Ruby 2.3.4, Rails 4.2.7, and FactoryGirl 4.0.0. We've run into the problem of having way too many traits in our base factories. We've started a project for replacing them and have a pattern in mind, but we need to be able to incrementally add our new factories to our production code while the original factories remain active.

Are there any reasonable ways to get this done?

This question, [Running two spec folders in Rails with RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892244/running-two-spec-folders-in-rails-with-rspec), seems to have the same problem, but separate branches is not a feasible solution for us.

Answer (score 0):

The first example [here](https://github.com/brennovich/cheat-ruby-sheets/blob/master/factory_bot.md) might be what you're looking for.

On one of the latest versions of factory-bot, you can set up concurrent factories like this:

```
factory :orignal_class do
  text 'original text'
end

factory :new_class_factory, class: OriginalClass do
  text 'this will be used instead when creating new_class_factory'
end
```

When you invoke the second factory, it will still be of the same class as the first factory, but will instead use the fields defined in its factory over the original factory.